# php image upload cant copy the actual file to the destination folder

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem when trying to upload an image to my mysql database which has 3 fields: id(auto increment), username and image location. The code is only inserting the image location to the database but not copying the actual image to the "profile_pics" directory. Please assist.

This is my code:

```
<?php

$connection=mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
$choose_db=mysql_select_db("ninjacity", $connection) or die (mysql_error());

if ($_SESSION['user'] && $_POST['submit'])
{
    function check() // to check if the pic already exists
    {
        $username=$_SESSION['user'];
        $choose_db;
        $sql_check="SELECT * FROM profile_pics WHERE username='$username'";
        $res_check=mysql_query($sql_check) or die (mysql_error());
        return mysql_num_rows($res_check);
    }

    $name=$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $tmp_name=$_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];


        $check=check();
        if ($check==1)
        {
            echo "You already have a profile pic. IF you wish to change it, please use the 'Edit my Profile' section";
        }
        else
        {
            $name;
            $tmp_name;
            $username=$_SESSION['user'];
            $location="profile_pics/$name";
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "profile_pics/".$name);

            $choose_db;
            $sql="INSERT INTO profile_pics VALUES ('$_POST[id]', '$username', '$location')";
            $res=mysql_query($sql) or die (mysql_error());
            print "Image successfully uploaded";
        }

}
else
{
    echo "Please fill all fields";
}


?>
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting. Check that the folder you store the upload files, has proper permissions.

Comment: and also try to echo out the $tmp_name and tell us

Comment: <form action="" name="upload" method="post">
        <table>
            
                <tr>
                    <td><input type="file" name="image" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>   
                    <td><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Upload" onClick="return verify()" /></td>
                </tr>
        </table>
</form>

Comment: when I try to echo out the $tmp_name its not displaying anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the permission of the profile_pics directory . It should be  777.

Or the issue related to the path (destination path of your directory )you have used  in move_uploaded_file .

Comment: 0777 permissions on a folder are the open security hole, never set rights to 0777.

Comment: @baldrs is right, you need to set the owner to the one is execcuting the server and permissions 744 are enough